# How to render end ticks always using d3 svg axis

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am not sure how the tick placement works with d3 svg axis. I tried playing with the ticks, tickSize options but essentially I get the start and end ticks "sometimes" with random data plotted

http://plnkr.co/edit/i5DBgfWzr2sa8Yugg2A8?p=preview

(Please ignore the angularjs aspect. The part that I am interested in is the following in d3)

```
   var make_x_axis = function () {
            return d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(x)
                  .orient("bottom") 
                  .ticks(5)
                  .tickFormat("")
                  .tickPadding(8); 
        };

        var make_y_axis = function () {
            return d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(y)
                  .ticks(6)
                  .orient("left")
                  .tickSize(10,10)
                  .tickPadding(8);
        };
```

How do I always get the start and end ticks rendered for both X and Y axis? I clearly always get the start and end tick lines on both X and y axis (Unsure how that is happening - I do not see a .tick element at that location in the chrome inspector) but the labels are missing. I can find the first and last tick and render a text with the tick label info but clearly I cannot always do it because sometime the axis gives me the start ticks and sometime it does not.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: The only way to do that is to set the tick values explicitly using `axis.tickValues()`.

Comment: @Lars, Thank you for that. I'll give that a try. I also see this x-axis and y-axis adding a path element with class domain that looks like the following  => |---------------------| I don't want the end ticks on it. Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: Hmm, you could remove the entire path, but then you'd have to draw a line to get the axis line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand your question, if you want to remove the ending x-axis ticks, you should set

**d3js V3**

```
.outerTickSize(0),
```

**d3js V4 - V6**

```
tickSizeOuter(0)
```

If you want to customize the ending ticks, you may use

```
.tickValues(y.ticks(5).concat( y.domain() ));
```

Have a look at my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9ucLqu2/) for a demonstration.

Comment: outerTickSize works pretty neatly. Regarding tickValues (as suggested by Lars), I think that is great but I am wondering how to best pick the samples from my data values i.e. My data looks like (t0,v0) (t1,v1)...(tn,vn) and I would like to definitely include to,tn on the x-axis and v0,vn on the y-axis and around 5 samples uniformly spaced on x and y axis. Is there a clever way to do this in d3?

Comment: Did you mean yAxis from y0 to yN, and xAxis do not need start tick and display x1 to xN? Did you see my fiddle above, is my xAxis and yAxis satisfied what you needs? Or if you want to include domain boundray into ticks, you could write like this: .tickValues(y.ticks(5).concat( y.domain() ))

Comment: Huan, Thank you for helping me with this. Your tickValues work on your bar chart very well but not with my series plot - See this - http://plnkr.co/edit/i5DBgfWzr2sa8Yugg2A8?p=preview .In terms of how you expressed your tickValues, I think that is the direction I should be headed towards but I am missing something. All my y ticks collapse at the same place in my plunkr when I do that...Any thoughts?

Comment: You want xAxis not start from 9/20? If you want to achieve that, i think you should use ordinal as xAxis scale instead of time scale, and when display the xAxis label, you can format the value to date time value, I'm not sure if there is another better approach for this.